# Handling DC Timeout Error on Powershell (The operation returned because the timeout limit was exceeded.)

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory, timeout

Good day!

would anyone know how to handle DC Timeout Errors?I am intermittently getting errors when running this line:

```
$HostnameCatch = Get-ADComputer -credential $credential -Filter $filter -Properties Name -ErrorAction Continue
```

For some reason, even I have specifically noted the -ErrorAction to Continue, the script still breaks when it encounters a DC timeout.

Here is the error message that we are getting:

Message : The operation returned because the timeout limit was exceeded.

```
InnerException : System.TimeoutException: This request operation sent to DC name did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:02:00). The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message. Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.
```

Here is the snippet of the code that we are using:

```
    $RCcount = 0
    
    $maxRetries = 3
    
    while ($RCcount -lt $maxRetries) {
    
    $HostnameCatch = Get-ADComputer -credential $credential -Filter $filter -Properties Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    if($?)
    
    {Write-host -Message "Hostname catch returned with no error, Domain Controller [$($LogonServer)] is responding as expected"
    
    break}
    
    else {
    
    $RCcount++

Write-host -Message "Domain Controller [$($LogonServer)] is not responding as expected to capture Hostname with possible SPN Duplicate. Retry Count $RCcount"

start-sleep 200}

}
```

I am basically asking the script to try these commands for atleast 3x before it moves on to another if statement, if $maxretries -eq $rccount, try one last time. catch the error.

Why does a DC timeout effectively stops a script regardless of erroraction? are there ways to circumvent this?

-Update the error is confirmed to be generated by our DCs, if we run the same/similar commands on the DC the script is using, it would sometimes give us timeout errors as well. Changes happening on our DCs lately - they have been promoting/demoting domain controllers as part of an OS upgrade project.

I am modifyiing this code to try and catch this problem and try again - as based on our experience, if a DC is giving out time outs, trying twice would usually let us go through.

Comment: if you want to suppress the errors, you'll have to use a try/catch statement: `try { Get-ADComputer ... } catch { .... }`. As far as I know, the AD module as a whole has always been bugged in regard to the `ErrorAction` preference.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this and let you know.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala there was no need to delete the answer, the answer was correct it just made incorrect assumptions of how the module works. I don't think you should delete it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, thanks man!  Just didn't want to give out the wrong information. I can't believe you found the code for it lol I was searching for it and finally gave up, then assumed why it didn't work.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala that repo has the disassembled code so it's not an exact replica but is as closer as we can get

Comment: I have made a mistake on my TryCatch Statement - I will try this again today. Thank you!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, try catch works as expected on get-adcomputer.

Thank you so much for your help guys and the attempts to explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @AbrahamZinala mentioned, erroraction preferences are not honored by the AD Module. This was further explained by @SantiagoSquarzon by leading us to the disambled codes of the AD Module.

Thanks guys for your help!